# std::ifstream accesses network files in mac osx

Tags: c++, macos, g++, fstream, distributed-filesystem

*How can I open a network shared file in OSX?  I tried with and without "cifs:".  also tried "192.168.xxx.xxx" but not working.  thanks.*

```
const std::string path_name("cifs://netshare.local/data/config.txt");

std::ifstream file( path_name.c_str(), std::ios::binary );

if (file.is_open())
{
    file.close();
    return true;
}
else
{
    // program comes in here
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try finding a path that works in the terminal first.  Can you say `ls -l cifs://netshare.local/data/config.txt` and see the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths to network shares mounted on Mac OS X appear under `/Volumes`, just like any other removable disk or disk image. If the share is called "data", it'll *usually* be mounted at `/Volumes/data`, but may end up at another path if that one isn't available.

(There's no way to directly access files on network shares that aren't mounted. So do that first.)

Comment: Thanks.  That's the answer I need: "no way to directly access files on network shares".

Comment: Note the qualifier: "…network shares **that aren't mounted**". It's perfectly possible once the share is mounted.